# LiftWeb Framework - overiding LiftRules.sessionInactivityTimeout

Tags: scala, tomcat, web, lift

Is there any possibility to set/override

```
LiftRules.sessionInactivityTimeout
```

val in Lift ??

I am a king of newbie in Scala and Lift..

I want to set different time for Lift session timeout than it is defined in web.xml in

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

For example i want to have Http container timeout set to 60 minutes (as configured above) and timeout in all Lift Session set to 25 minutes.

Is there any other way in Lift to do that (instead of somehow using LiftRules.sessionInactivityTimeout) ??

Thanks

Comment: As much as I love Stackoverflow, I highly recommend going to the [Lift user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb) for help with this.

Answer (score 3):

`sessionInactivityTimeout` is a [`FactoryMaker`](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.http.Factory), not a straight value. Therefore, you can set the default value for the `FactoryMaker` without changing the value of `sessionInactivityTimeout`. I believe this should do what you are looking for.

```
LiftRules.sessionInactivityTimeout.default.set(Full(25l))
```

You can see more info about the dependency injections [here](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-8.2.html#toc-Subsection-8.2.2).

Comment: Following readers be careful: 25l are 25 ms, not 25mins! use: ```Full(1000l*60*25)```